# custom mapping to make dge consistent with dw, de, and db?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, keyword, operator-pending-mode

#### Situation

Recently I was investigating the behaviour of word motions in vim and to me it seems like `ge` is grossly inconsistent with the other 3. Here is an example with `^` showing the cursor:

```
word1 word2        de:  wo word2         dw:   woword2
  ^

word1 word2        db:  word1 rd2        dge:  wordd2
        ^
```

It seems to me that `dge` is inconsistent in 2 ways:

1. It deletes the character the cursor is on (inconsistent with db)
2. It deletes the last character of the previous word (inconsistent with dw)

#### What I tried

The following fixed the issue with leaving the character the cursor was on:

```
onoremap ge vge
```

And the following fixes the issue with leaving the last character on the previous word:

```
onoremap <expr> ge ":<c-u>normal! gel<cr>"
```

But I cannot find a convenient way to combine these two behaviours.

#### Question

How can I remap `ge` so it behaves this way:

```
word1 word2        dge:  word1rd2
        ^
```

Also, maybe my perception about `ge` being inconsistent is wrong?
Would be very interested in hearing comments disputing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way to fix `ge` is to make a backwards search:

```
onoremap ge :call search('\>', 'b')<CR>
```

You can use a more complex regex if you want.

Or, you could also move to the right position using the `normal` command:

```
onoremap ge :normal!ge<SPACE><CR>

" Or, with working counts (version from @Karolis_Koncevičius):

onoremap ge :execute "normal! " . v:count1 . "ge<space>"<cr>
```

Note that we use `<SPACE>` here, and not `l` or `<RIGHT>`, because `<SPACE>` will allow us to get back on the right line if we use `dge` on the fist word of the line. **Disclaimer** - This breaks if the line above ends with whitespaces.

---

As you underline in the comments, those 2 functions can break in some cases. For a foolproof `ge`, I see no other way than to write a small function:

```
function! BetterGE()
    let curline = line('.')
    normal! gel

    if line('.') != curline
        call setpos('.', [0, curline, 1, 0])
    endif
endfunction

onoremap ge :call BetterGE()<CR>
```

This function will call the default `ge`, move one character to the right, and if the line is not the same as the initial one, we bring back the cursor on the 1st column of the initial line.

This doesn't seem to break in any of the mentioned cases.

---

The `ge` motion seem inconsistent indeed, but it makes sense: it's an inclusive character-wise motion, which means that:

> When inclusive, the start and end position of the motion are included in the operation.

(from `:h inclusive`)

So that's why the character under the cursor and the last character of the previous word are deleted

Also, as [@filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden) noted:

> exclusive motions are always exclusive to the right, not to the direction the motion is going. That's why db being an exclusive motion excludes the character the cursor was on... And that's why ge isn't an exclusive motion, because exclusive-to-the-left would make sense, but the regular exclusive doesn't make as much sense

Comment: Awesome answer! Simple and does what's requested. I only found one corner case, which is when using `dge` at the first word in the line after a line that doesn't end on whitespace. That will "eat" the last character of the previous line, unless `'virtualedit'` includes 'onemore', which allows the cursor to sit at the end of the line... But yeah, this is really pretty good!

Comment: Regarding the inconsistency, I'd explain that that's mainly because exclusive motions are always exclusive to the *right*, not to the direction the motion is going. That's why `db` being an exclusive motion excludes the character the cursor was on... And that's why `ge` isn't an exclusive motion, because exclusive-to-the-left would make sense, but the regular exclusive doesn't make as much sense...

Comment: @Zorzi thank you for the answer, it goes into the right direction, but both maps are still lacking. The first one for example goes to the end of the word but it fails to go to non-keyword characters. The second one will fail in some situations, like working on the first word of the line.

Comment: Yup, well spoted. I added a 3rd solution which should work!

Comment: @Zorzi, I think I found a better solution: we can replace the `l` with `<space>` in the `gel` command, so it becomes `ge<space>`. If you do not see any downsides to that, maybe you can add that, and I will accept the answer?

Comment: I actually thought about that, but if the previous line ends with white spaces, it breaks.. I will add it to my answer nonetheless

Comment: I think `dge` from the first word in a line should still merge it with the preceding line, no? This function doesn't do that... (That's the problem with tweaking those... So many corner cases. It's definitely *possible* to write a function that will get all corner cases right, but it's surely hard to do so and to keep testing for all of them...)

Comment: From my point of view, `dge` shouldn't merge the lines, just like `dw` doesn't merge lines when you use it on the last word of the line. It wouldn't be too hard to do if we want it to merge though

Comment: @Zorzi ah I see, it still breaks. I never have trailing white space in my code, so missed this corner case...

Comment: @Zorzi Yeah, `dw` doesn't merge lines, but `d2w` does. So does `d2b` when on the first word of the line. `ge` is a different beast since it always moves to the *previous* word, so I fell that should be the behavior... Also, does the "new" `ge` work with counts? (Like I mentioned, soooo many corner cases... I really feel this becomes too much effort to a small gain very quickly...)

Comment: @filbranden very good observation, currently it will not work with counts, but here is the version that does: `onoremap E :execute "normal! " . v:count1 . "ge<space>"<cr>`. It probably still will be missing a few edge cases, like you mentioned