# 'de' and 'e' is not analogous to 'dw' and 'w'

Tags: normal-mode

(Context: I am doing the vim tutor)

Exploring 'e' and 'w' commands I noticed 'e' places the cursor on top of the last letter of the current word, and if I type 'de' with the cursor somwhere between the word, it deletes up to the last letter of the word (including it). However, 'w' places the cursor on top of the beginning of the next word but 'dw' does not include that letter.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24687/10604, https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6194/10604

Comment: I'm sure this is partly because of the POSIX spec for vi, which special cases `w`, `e` as motions versus regular movement (and also describes the `c` case). Note that in vim's help it's described by "exclusive" versus "inclusive" motions.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what your question is. Are you asking _why_ it works like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is expected behaviour.
'dw' deletes current word, while 'w' will find the next word.
'de' deletes to (including) end of word, while 'e' will find the next end of a word.

Comment: I believe the demand is to understand in vim terms why the behavior is different. You answer may lack justification in term of vim concepts.